# I/O exception when calling webservice several times from Mule 3.2

Tags: cxf, mule

I am using Mule ESB 3.2 to call a webservice. Since the response is paged I need to call this service several times and merge the result. When calling the wevservice the second time I get an I/O exception in Mule and I cannot see anything on the called service side. 
I have also tried to mock the service using SOAP UI with the same result.

Error from Mule log (MULE_ERROR-42999):

```
   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

This is my mule config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" 
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/3.2/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/3.2/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.2/mule-http.xsd">

<configuration defaultResponseTimeout="30000" />

<custom-transformer class="com.mutnelat.transform.ComingEvents"
    name="ComingEvents">
    <spring:property name="eventBrandIdDefault" value="${eventBrandIdDefault}" />
    <spring:property name="fatherClassificationId" value="${fatherClassificationId}" />
</custom-transformer>

<custom-transformer class="com.mutnelat.transform.ComingEventsResponse"
    name="ComingEventsResponse" mimeType="text/plain" />

<custom-transformer class="com.mutnelat.transform.PageCount" name="PageCount"/>

<!-- Eventlist flows -->

<flow name="EventList" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="${web.service.url}/events" exchange-pattern="request-response">
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <flow-ref name="GetEventsFromCRM" />
    <transformer ref="PageCount" />
    <choice>
        <when evaluator="groovy"
            expression="message.getSessionProperty('page_count') > 0">
            <logger level="INFO" message="More than one page..." />
            <flow-ref name="GetEventsFromCRM" />
        </when>
    </choice>
    <transformer ref="ComingEventsResponse" />
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer name="transform-response-fi"
        xsl-file="events.xsl" mimeType="text/xml" />
</flow>

<!-- Eventlist subflows -->

<flow name="GetEventsFromCRM" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <transformer ref="ComingEvents" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Calling..." />      
    <http:outbound-endpoint host="${adapter.host}" method="GET"
        port="${adapter.port}" path="crmService" user="${adapter.username}"
        password="${adapter.password}">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="sendFetchXml" serviceClass="com.mutnelat.adapter.ws.CRMService" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Reveived coming events" />
</flow>
```

Comment: This seems to be a memory problem since the response I get from the service is rather large. I found this issue in the Mule jira: http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5641